# Is there a way to make entities defined in an EDMX model spread out so they aren't overlapping?

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio

I've got a VERY large entity model that was handed to me, and the entity definitions visually overlap themselves in may places.  I'd rearrange them by hand, but it's over 150 tables.

Is there a way to spread them out automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The EDMX designer has an automatic layout feature:

Right click in the designer -> `Diagram` -> `Layout Diagram`